# Ruby - Read and Write 'EOF' Character

Tags: ruby, io, eof

I have come across a document which I need to parse that contains an old MS-DOS EOF character (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character). The issue is that Ruby does not read past this character. What I need to do, however, is read the line which contains this character and write it back unchanged.
I assume writing the character shouldn't be too difficult, as I know the ASCII code, the main issue is that Ruby simply stops reading the file after it encounters this character.
I use something like the following code:

```
lineNumber = 0
File.foreach(sourcePath) do |li|
     lineNumber = lineNumber + 1
end
puts lineNumber
```

Comment: What do you use to read from a file? I experience no problem reading past that symbol under Linux: `p File.read my_file.path #⇒"Content \u001A Content 2"`. BTW, I can’t even guess why ruby won’t read past it.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Added a code snippet. Using windows as coding environment.

Comment: So what’s the problem to read the whole file, do whatever you want and write it back as I shew above?

Comment: The file is 2-5GB in size, so I need to read line by line.

Comment: The second argument to `foreach` is the separator to use. I doubt you want to split the file on the letter `r`. Do you mean "\r", or do you want `:mode => 'r'` (or something else)?

Comment: Whoops, I actually copied it incorrectly. I did not have any second argument. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Does reading in binary mode help (`:mode => 'rb'`)?